# Cannot access UIButton through iVar / property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uibutton, instance-variables

I created an UIButton programmatically and put it into a property:

```
    UIButton *button = _homeButton; 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeButton"];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkHide:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [[self superview] insertSubview:button belowSubview:self];
```

Now, lets check the selector:
by some reason, this works:

```
- (void)checkHide:(UIButton *)sender {
        [sender removeFromSuperview];
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
- (void)checkHide:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_homeButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Why do I need the latter solution? Because I would like to remove this particular button by tapping another button. So, I can't get any sender from it. Still, the code in `checkHide` method is being executed anyway, the case, I cannot manipulate with button using iVar or property. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your pointers correctly.  First you are setting your "button" pointer to your _homeButton.  In the third line you are then setting your "button" pointer to a new UIButton.
Basically, this:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

cancels out this:

```
UIButton *button = _homeButton;
```

See Joel's answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you, guys! As both answers were sent at the same time with the same solution, I flipped a coin.

Comment: I think Joel beat me by 17 seconds but I'm not going to tell anyone.

Comment: I heard that. I'm telling.

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign _homeButton in your code. Try this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeButton"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkHide:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[[self superview] insertSubview:button belowSubview:self];
_homeButton = button;
```